# JavaScript mapping numbers to string

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I problem is in javaScript I want a list of cities with each city associated with a range of temperature such as Manchester 10-20, London 21-30. When a user inputs a temperature it tells the associated city (user inputted 22 London will be outputted).

*My initial idea was to have a String array of cities then map users input to the index of the city. So user inputs 22 it maps it to index 2 (London).*

*But inputting a city later on will be really hard.*

*My second idea was just a ton if else statements starting with the lowest band.*

These are my two ideas, I was wondering what it the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that two cities will never have overlapping *temperature* ranges?

Comment: Learn about [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @domdom yeah no overlaps

Comment: I was wondering if a json file would work

Answer (score 1):

Make a 3 dimension

```
array [City][low-temp][high-temp]
```

If a user gives input run all cities and compare if the input is

```
low-temp < input < high-temp
```

and return list of cities which meet the condition.

Comment: I don't know if a 3d array is the best way, by temperature are not necessarily going to start at 0, they may even go below 0

Answer (score 0):

Don't use arrays for this.  Assuming city names are unique (if they aren't then you need to find a way to make them unique via state/province/some other hierarchical identifier)

```js
var cityToTempRange = {
  <city name>: {
    low: <low temp>
    , high: <high temp>
  }
  , <city name>: ...
};
```

This is a better representation of your data and will remove the need to iterate through your array to find the city you're looking for.

To find a list of city names, it would be best to use a utility library such as [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pickBy)

```js
function getCitiesFromTemp(requestedTemp) {
  return _(cityToTempRange)
    .pickBy(cityHasTemp)
    .keys()
    .value();

  function cityHasTemp(rangeObj) {
    return rangeObj.low <= requestedTemp
      && rangeObj.high >= requestedTemp;
  }
}
```

which, with the following test

```
var cityToTempRange = {
  Manchester: {
    low: 10
    , high: 20
  }
  , London: {
    low: 21
    , high: 30
  }
};


console.log(getCitiesFromTemp(21));
```

prints `['London']`

Comment: So, given a temperature, how *would* he find/access the correct city? -- well, your edit now shows how. :)

Comment: Glad to help.  And if you are hesitant to bring in a library - I can write the 'pickBy' and 'keys' portion as standalone functions.

Comment: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>`

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/lodash.js/

Comment: @aaaaaa cheers again, I was also looking a javaScript Databases, such as Taffy. Just wondering what is your opinion on these.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it.

If there are no overlaps and the difference between the temperature ranges is 10. Then just create an array of cities and order them as per the low temperature.

When user inputs a value, divide it by 10 and get the city/cities at that index in the array.

Array can look like

```
myCitiesArray = [
{
    cities: chicago, new york
    low-temp: 11,
    high-temp: 20
},
{
    cities: xyz
    low-temp: 21,
    high-temp: 30
},
.
.
]

index = Math.floor(UserInput/10);
```

Use this if you have negative temperature ranges also

```
index = ~~(userInput / 10);
```

You need to have a check at border values. So if there is no remainder, index = index - 1;

```
index = userInput % 10 === 0 ? index-1 : index;
```

Comment: I was thinking the same. But from OP's example, it looks like the temperature ranges are not always same in size (11 for Manchester, 10 for London). But if they are, this would be the most elegant way I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array with objects and iterate the data for the cities.

I suggest to allow overlapping temperatures, because the reality reflects that.

```js
function getCities(temperature) {
    return data.
        filter(function (a) {
            return temperature >= a.min && temperature <= a.max;
        }).
        map(function (a) {
            return a.city;
        });
}

var data = [
        { city: 'Manchester', min: 10, max: 20 },
        { city: 'London', min: 21, max: 30 }
    ];         
    
console.log(getCities(22));
console.log(getCities(10));
```

Comment: thank you after doing some research this seems to the best way.